# Flutter TextField for input time

Tags: flutter, textfield

As I wrote in the title I'd like to create a specific TextField to enter time.
More in depth I wanted the user to enter just 4 digits and the field automatically shows somethings like that  12:23, so automatically the field will insert ":" character.

An empty TextField will show nothing.
When user enters digits TextField will show : 1    --> 12    --> 12:2   --> 12:23
I've tried controller but I'm not able to reach my purpose.
Can someone help me?

thank you, have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using two containers separated by a ":", all inside a parent container. I'm saving hours and minutes into two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter

Custom format

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [
        MaskedInputFormatter('##:##'))
    ],
),
```

Comment: This works, at least for the ":" character.
What if I'd like to create a "smart function" to control 00<hours<24 and  00<min<60 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      maxLength: 5,
      onChanged: (value){
        if(_controller.text.length==2){
          _controller.text = _controller.text + ":";
        }
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.
After the second digit it adds the ":" but after I'm not able to write any other character. Also if I try to modify a number I'll obtain another ":" also if it's already in the controller.